# Why aren't style triggers operating on cell templated columns in GridView?

Tags: wpf, triggers

I have a ListView to display log events. A style trigger is defined to alter the colour of the row depending on the log severity. Works ok except for one column which uses a CellTemplate. The Label items keep there normal colour.

```
<ListView x:Name="LogEvents" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="9">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level.DisplayName}" Value="ERROR">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSalmon"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level.DisplayName}" Value="INFO">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level.DisplayName}" Value="DEBUG">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level.DisplayName}" Value="WARN">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Level.DisplayName}" Value="FATAL">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="GridView1">
            <GridViewColumn Header="TimeStamp" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TimeStamp, ConverterCulture=de-DE, StringFormat=HH:mm:ss.fff}"/>
            <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Level}" Header="Level" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Thread" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ThreadName}"  />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Message" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RenderedMessage}"  />
            <!--<GridViewColumn Header="UserName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}"  />-->
            <GridViewColumn Header="Class.Method">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=LocationInformation.ClassName}" Padding="0"/>
                            <Label Content="." Padding="0"/>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=LocationInformation.MethodName}" Padding="0"/>
                            <Label Content="(" Padding="0"/>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=LocationInformation.LineNumber}" Padding="0"/>
                            <Label Content=")" Padding="0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

For example, if the Level=Debug, the 'Class.Method' column receives the appropriate Background (LightGrey) but the Forground remains Black (default).

What do I have to do here? Repeat the Style.Triggers for x:Type Labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked. Not sure if there is a nicer way but it is fairly compact.

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <!-- Added this section so Label inherits from Parent ListViewItem -->
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=Foreground}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <Label  ...
```